# How can I make VS Code not try to save files before debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

VS Code prompts me to save untitled file before run/debug.

Is there a setting to turn this off?

Comment: `debug.saveBeforeStart` need VSC v1.54

Comment: Thank you very much, question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Put `"debug.saveBeforeStart": "none",` in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). Quoting from defaultSettings.json:

> ```json
> // Controls what editors to save before starting a debug session.
> //  - allEditorsInActiveGroup: Save all editors in the active group before starting a debug session.
> //  - nonUntitledEditorsInActiveGroup: Save all editors in the active group except untitled ones before starting a debug session.
> //  - none: Don't save any editors before starting a debug session.
> "debug.saveBeforeStart": "allEditorsInActiveGroup",
> ```