# How to prevent saving changes when running code in VS Code (Python)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, save, settings, auto, autosave

Whenever I add or change code in a script and press Ctrl-F5, it automatically saves it. I would like to prevent this. I checked that Auto Save is off, and that Save Before Run in Settings is also off, but it still automatically saves the script before running it.

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66570480/11107541 ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think you can, since it needs to be a file that it can run before running it.

Comment: So that means that it can't run/interpret a script directly from the editor? This makes it difficult to test out different scenarios and then restore the original if the new code doesn't work. Unless I "Save As" each time, or repeat Undo.
Unless I'm missing something. I am, after all, a relative newbie to Python and VS Code....

Comment: I am speculating, but it needs a file to run so either you save a temporary file (as you are saying) or you can use git to track the changes and roll back to the working version if you have an issue with the new code. If you are doing so in a single session undo (Ctrl+Z ) will work to go back, but if you close the editor it won't.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).